# ios 7 support for existing iPad app

Tags: ios, ios7

I have existing iPad app supporting iOS 5 and 6.
Can anybody help me to list down item that I need to take care while supporting iOS 7?

One thing I noticed that in existing code `((UITableView*)self.superview)` in `UITableViewCell` doesn't work. superview of `UITableViewCell` is `UITableViewWrapperView` that need to be fixed in existing code.

Comment: Read Apple's iOS 7 transition guide and test every single bit of your app.

Comment: i had some problem with navigation bar.

Comment: Thanks for responses.
As rmaddy said Apple has summarized the about UI related points that need to be focused. 
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174

My concern here is the points that can be easily not observed(Non UI).
as Ganapathy said there are issues in threads and fixed by using dispatch_queue(GCD with delay).

Comment: To solve that UITableViewCell superview, You can customise the cell and keep a property that holds the superview of the cell and set the superview while creating the table view in TableView data source method

Comment: Thanks @Nagaraj, but my concern here is to identify the points that need to taken care while supporting iOS7. we will find out solutions to the issues anyway.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

The things are:
1. Navigation bar height and view style are different
2. Status bar is transparent in iOS 7 as in iOS 6 it was opaque.
3. Small thing is about the tint color. By default it is light blue in iOS 7.
4. Button borders have been removed.

Comment: I hope you don't think this is a complete list.

Answer (score 0):

Issue's i have faced while running the app in IOS 7.

1. Status bar issue (view controller get overlaps 20 pixel.)

   [FixForStatusBarIssue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19025547/1545180)
2. Customize alert view won't work in IOS7. (We can't customize the alert view in IOS 7.)

   My Fix -> You need to customize the view exactly like u want because you can't customize alert view in IOS7.
3. Issues related to threads.

   My Fix -> Use dispatch_queue(GCD with delay) in case of UI not responding (Presenting a view controller from background thread.)
4. Zbar sdk memory leaks while presenting and dismissing the SDK (more than 5 times app getting slow.)

   [FixForZbarMemoryLeakIssue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19651568/1545180)

this are the issues i have faced. fixes i have suggested working fine for me. You just use it if you need hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

[Apple's iOS 7 UI Transition guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/)

Read descriptions of every single element you used in your app.

And be aware of the style and position of the bars (navigation bar/tab bar/tool bar...).

iOS 7 has changed a lot in view hierarchies, you can use [Reveal](http://revealapp.com/) to make things easier.