# ZBar SDK slowing down in IOS7

Tags: ios, ios7, zbar-sdk, zbar

I am trying to implement some qr code reader using ZBar.
After a while I did manage to do reading, but after several readings the app tends to get slower and slower (until practically unresponsive).
This SDK is compatible with iOS7 ?
Frameworks : libiconv.dylib,libinfo.dylib, QuartzCore, CoreVideo,CoreMedia,AVFoundation,CoreGraphics,UIKit,XCTest

```
- (IBAction)scan:(id)sender {
    //initialize the reader and provide some config instructions
    ZBarReaderViewController *reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
    reader.readerDelegate = self;

    [reader.scanner setSymbology: ZBAR_I25
                          config: ZBAR_CFG_ENABLE
                              to: 1];
    reader.cameraFlashMode=UIImagePickerControllerCameraFlashModeOff;
    reader.readerView.zoom = 1.0; // define camera zoom property

    //show the scanning/camera mode
    [self presentModalViewController:reader animated:YES];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info {

    //this contains your result from the scan
    id results = [info objectForKey: ZBarReaderControllerResults];

    //create a symbol object to attach the response data to
    ZBarSymbol *symbol = nil;

    //add the symbol properties from the result
    //so you can access it
    for(symbol in results){

        //symbol.data holds the value
        NSString *upcString = symbol.data;

        //print to the console
        NSLog(@"the value of the scanned UPC is: %@",upcString);

        NSMutableString *message = [[NSMutableString alloc]
                                    initWithString: @"Scanned Barcode: "];

        [message appendString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
                               upcString]];

        //Create UIAlertView alert
        UIAlertView  *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Product Barcode" message: message delegate:self
                               cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles: nil];

        self.viewResult.text = upcString;
        [alert show];
        //After some time
        [alert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];

        //make the reader view go away
        [reader dismissModalViewControllerAnimated: YES];
    }

}
```

EDIT : After 4 or 5 readings, this is the memory and CPU consumption -> http://diogomend.me/images/capt.png. Christ :D

Comment: If you need to deploy only on iOS7 I suggest you to use the new APIs of AVFoundation to detect barcode, qrcode and similar

Comment: Why you don't use the AVCaptureSession (natif) in iOS7 to scan bar code. Take a look on this tutorial : http://www.renaudpradenc.com/?p=453

Comment: the app will have to work as well on iOS6 :( In iOS6 i don't have this problem of slowing down... strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, after checking this issue [Memory related issue of ZBarReaderViewController in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19633708/memory-related-issue-of-zbarreaderviewcontroller-in-ios-7), I did manage to solve the problem.
The lines I've added are the following:

(in my viewcontroller.h)

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) ZBarReaderViewController *reader;
```

(in my viewcontroller.m)

```
if(self.reader) 
{
    [self.reader.readerView stop]; 
    for(UIView *subViews in self.reader.view.subviews) 
    [subViews removeFromSuperview];
    [self.reader.view removeFromSuperview];
    self.reader.view = nil;
}
_reader = [ZBarReaderViewController new];
```